# Formatted output with leading zeros in Fortran

Tags: formatting, fortran

I have some decimal numbers that I need to write to a text file with leading zeros when appropriate.  I've done some research on this, and everything I've seen suggests something like:

```
  REAL VALUE
  INTEGER IVALUE

  IF (VALUE.LT.0) THEN
    IVALUE = CEILING(VALUE)
  ELSE
    IVALUE = FLOOR(VALUE)
  ENDIF
  WRITE(*,1) IVALUE, ABS(VALUE)-ABS(IVALUE)
1 FORMAT(I3.3,F5.4)
```

As I understand it, the `IF` block and `ABS` parts should allow this to work for all values on -100 < VALUE < 1000.  If I set `VALUE = 12.3456`, the code above should produce "012.3456" as the output, and it does.  However if I have something like `VALUE = -12.3456`, I'm getting "(3 asterisks).3456" as my output.  I know the asterisks usually shows up when there are not enough characters provided for in the `FORMAT` statement, but 3 should be enough in this example (1 character for the "-" and two characters for "12").  I haven't tested this yet with something like `VALUE = -9.876`, but I'd expect the output to be "-09.8760".

Is there something wrong in my understanding of how this works? Or is there some other limitation of this technique that I'm violating?

UPDATE: Okay I've looked into this some more, and it seems to be a combination of a negative value and the `I3.3` format.  If VALUE is positive and I have the `I3.3`, it will put leading zeros as expected.  If VALUE is negative and I only have `I3` as my format, I get the correct value output, but it will be padded with spaces before the negative sign instead of padded with zeros after the negative (so -9.8765 is output as " -9.8765", but that leading space breaks what I'm using the .txt file for, so it's not acceptable).

Comment: as a kludge you could put the write inside the if, print a '-' as a string for the neg case followed by the abs(int) formatted as you like.  I expect the format experts will come up with a proper solution though.

Comment: @george: haha I was just writing up my answer when you posted this =).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tho problem is with your integer data edit descriptor. With `I3.3` you require at least 3 digits and the field width is only 3. There is no place for the minus sign. Use `I4.3` or, In Fortran 95 and above, `I0.3`.

Answer to your edit: Use `I0.3`, it uses the minimum number of characters necessary.

**But finally, you just probably want this: `WRITE(*,'(f0.3)') VALUE`**

Comment: Ahh, so the I3.3 is specifying each character needs to be a number, the minus sign isn't allow to be in those spots.  I get it now.  Yep, `I0.3` is going to do the trick. Thanks!!

Comment: after spending too much time on this I discovered my compiler also supports f0.n to print a float value in the mimimum field width, which I think is what he actually wants. I dont know though if this (or I0) is standard or in what version it became so.

Comment: You are right, I did not study the rest of the question enough. It came up in Fortran 95.

Comment: @george: ugh, wish I had noticed that before I started all of this. F0.3 is exactly what I was looking for from the beginning, but I found other sites that said such a thing doesn't exist (they must not have been updated maybe? Or they were saying that's the only way on F77 maybe? w/e), and the splitting into integer and decimal parts was the only way to do this.  What's more, I didn't actually see this post until after I already spent 1/2 day updating all my code with `I0.3,F5.4`. Ah well, for future reference I guess. That's what I get for believing everything I read on the internet...

Comment: what if I want to use like `write(*,'(f0.2)')` but still want put a leading zero if there is none e.g. `0.12` , how do I do that?  `f0.2` writes as `.12`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I could get what I'm looking for by changing it up a little bit to

```
  REAL VALUE
  INTEGER IVALUE

  IF (VALUE.LT.0) THEN
    WRITE(*,1) FLOOR(ABS(IVALUE)), ABS(VALUE)-FLOOR(ABS(VALUE))
1   FORMAT('-',I2.2,F5.4)    
  ELSE
    WRITE(*,2) FLOOR(VALUE), ABS(VALUE)-FLOOR(BS(VALUE))
2   FORMAT(I3.3,F5.4)
  ENDIF
```

But this feels a lot clunkier, and in reality I'm going to try to be writing multiple values in the same line, which will lead to really messy `IF` blocks or complex cursor movement, which I'd like to avoid if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

as another way to skin the cat.. I'd prefer not to do arithmatic on the data at all but just work on the format:

```
character*8 fstring/'(f000.4)'/
val=12.34
if(val.gt.1)then
    write(fstring(3:5),'(i0)')6+floor(log10(val))
elseif(val.lt.-1)then
    write(fstring(3:5),'(i0)')7+floor(log10(-val))
elseif(val.ge.0)
    write(fstring(3:5),'(i0)')6
else
    write(fstring(3:5),'(i0)')7
endif
write(*,fstring)val
```

just for fun with modern fortran that supports character functions you can roll that up in a function and end up with a construct like this:

```
write(*,'('//fstring(val1)//','//fstring(val2)//')')val1,val2
```